# "The select statement includes a reserved word or an argument name that is misspelled"

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am unable to figure out why this message keeps appearing.

> The select statement includes a reserved word or an argument name that is misspelled.

However, I am unable to find the problem in my code.

Can anyone help and identify what am I missing?

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
A.CINBR, SUM(C.EAANU) AS EAANU, SUM(C.MPRPQ) AS ONORD, 
   IIF(C.ITCLS = "DPAR","DPAR",""),
   IIF(C.ITCLS = "CONE","CONE",""),
   IIF(C.ITCLS = "PART","PART",""),
   IIF(C.ITCLS = "SPDY","SPDY",""),
FROM AMFLIB.PSTDTL A LEFT OUTER JOIN
    AMFLIB.ITEMBL C ON A.PINBR = C.ITNBR RIGHT OUTER JOIN
    INTonSHELF D ON A.CINBR = D .ITNBR
WHERE C.EAANU > 0
GROUP BY A.CINBR, C.ITCLS
ORDER BY A.CINBR
```

Comment: The extra comma at the end of the last line (see @Jiggles32 answer)  is causing Access to think you have a field called `FROM` - which is the reserved word it's referring to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disregard what Access is saying, most of the time, it is unhelpful.

That being said the following are the problems:

```
SELECT DISTINCT A.CINBR
    ,SUM(C.EAANU) AS EAANU
    ,SUM(C.MPRPQ) AS ONORD
    ,IIF(C.ITCLS = "DPAR", "DPAR", "")
    ,IIF(C.ITCLS = "CONE", "CONE", "")
    ,IIF(C.ITCLS = "PART", "PART", "")
    ,IIF(C.ITCLS = "SPDY", "SPDY", "")
FROM AMFLIB.PSTDTL A
LEFT JOIN AMFLIB.ITEMBL C ON A.PINBR = C.ITNBR
RIGHT JOIN INTonSHELF D ON A.CINBR = D.ITNBR
WHERE C.EAANU > 0
GROUP BY A.CINBR
    ,C.ITCLS
ORDER BY A.CINBR
```

Specifically, this line was causing issues: `IIF(C.ITCLS = "SPDY","SPDY",""),` There was an extra comma attached to the SELECT statement.

Additionally Access does not support `LEFT OUTER JOIN` or `RIGHT OUTER JOIN` as functions

Comment: Thank you. Not sure why I did not catch that.